# Expo go is not downloading in ios simulator on mac(M1 Chip, Xcode-14, MacOS-Ventura-13)

Tags: ios, react-native, macos, expo

I have upgraded my mac os version into the latest one(Ventura 13) and downloaded xcode 14.
My node js version is 16.14.2 and I have installed expo-cli.
I have initiated a new project e.g. testApp with blank typescript project.
After all installing, when I hit command on terminal in project, `yarn ios`, it triggers to download `expo go` but it doesn't go to 100%. Sometimes it stops at 95%.
[image]
This happens every time and I tried every possible way but failed e.g downgrading expo cli and reinstalling xcode.
Could anyone help me this?
Here are the steps to reproduce.

```
1, npm install -g expo-cli
2, expo init testApp
3, cd testApp
4, yarn ios
```

Comment: Did you just try leave it for a while? If no error is thrown, I'd assume it's doing something or trying at least.

Comment: Hi, @AleksandarZoric thank you for your quick response. Yes, I have tried to leave as it is for 3 hours but still the same. It doesn't move forward.